# Unique strong solution of $X_t=t+\int_0^tX_sdW_s$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $(W_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a standard brownian motion. Using Ito's lemma, I was able to show that

$$X_t:=\exp(W_t-\frac{1}{2}t)\int_0^t\exp(-(W_s-\frac{1}{2}s))ds$$

solves

$$X_t=t+\int_0^tX_sdW_s$$

Therefore $X$ is a strong solution of this equation.

Now I wonder if this solution is unique and if it relates to the function I was using in Ito's lemma, which is

$$f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\quad f(x_1,x_2)=\exp(x_1)\cdot x_2,$$

such that

$$X_t=f\big(W_t-\frac{1}{2}t,\int_0^t\exp(-(W_s-\frac{1}{2}s))ds\big)$$

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general, a stochastic differential equation has a unique solution, subject to some relatively mild hypotheses on the coefficients (which are satisfied here). A reference to the precise theorem can be found in the book by Oksendal, or here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Existence_and_uniqueness_of_solutions

Comment: Thank you! As seen in my question, it holds $dX_t=X_tdW_t=\mu(X_t,t)dt+\sigma(X_t,t)dW_t$ for $\mu=0$ and $\sigma(x,t)=x$. Since $|\sigma(x,t)|=|x|\le 1+|x|$ and $|\sigma(x,t)-\sigma(y,t)|=|x-y|\le |x-y|$, I find, that $X$ is the unique solution to the initial value $X_0=0$. Is this right?

Comment: yep that's right!

Comment: Ops! I guess, it has to be $dX_t=dt+X_tdW_t$. However... $\mu(x,t)=1$, $\sigma(x,t)=x$ and $|\mu(x,t)|+|\sigma(x,t)|=1+|x|$, $|\mu(x,t)-\mu(y,t)|+|\sigma(x,t)-\sigma(y,t)|=|x-y|$